Как получить доступ к параметрам поля модели Django?
Например есть класс:
class Support(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Наименование')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')

Надо что-то вроде:

def get_verbose_names(self):
    return {'title': title.verbose_name, 'description': description.verbose_name)

А также в template:
<li class="active"><a href="#description" data-toggle="tab">{{ support.title.verbose_name }} = {{ support.title }}</a></li>

Ну или:
<li class="active"><a href="#description" data-toggle="tab">{{ support.get_verbose_names.title }} = {{ support.title }}</a></li>
                        

Не подкинете вариантов новичку? Заранее спасибо.
PS. Уточнение. Предполагается, что сами поля и их verbose_name править нельзя. Типа создать заранее словарь со значениями, раздать в verbose_name и вернуть какой-нибудь функцией для доступа в контексте
